# Equation to Specify Lexicographical Ordering?

Tags: ordinals, well-orders, ordinal-analysis

I am not a mathematician, but I need to specify, precisely, a special way to sort an arbitrary list of [ASCII](https://www.asciitable.com/) strings<sup>1</sup>, with the addition of some special rules for a small set of specific characters. I believe this is called "lexicographical ordering" or "collation" rules.

For an extremely simple example, let's say I want $\text{A} < \text{B} < \text{C} < \text{F} < \text{E} < \text{D}$. For that, I am imagining something like the following:

$
\newcommand{\coloneqq}{\mathrel{\mathop:}\mathrel{\mkern-1.2mu}=}
 C \coloneqq \{ \text{A}, \text{B}, \text{C}, \text{D}, \text{E}, \text{F}, \text{G} \} \\
 f(c) \colon C \to \mathbb{N} \\
 O \coloneqq \{ (\text{A}, 1), (\text{B}, 2), (\text{C}, 3), (\text{F}, 4), (\text{E}, 5), (\text{D}, 6) \} \\
 f_c \coloneqq \{ i \in \mathbb{N} \mid \exists ((c, i) \in O)\}
$

I think this is incorrect because I end up with the function returning a *set* instead of a number I can use for comparison. (E.g., to test if $f(\text{F}) < f(\text{C})$.)

How can I do this properly? What are some keywords I could search for to read more about this?

---

<sup>1</sup> Eventually, I would like to override the [Unicode® collation algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/), but let's take that out of scope to keep this simple. I was hoping that algorithm might contain the answer I need, but it is very complex, and I see no sign of a general equation.

Comment: Most computer sorting algorithms that I am aware of allow you to specify a routine to compare two items of your list.  The default string comparison algorithms will use lexicographic order, but you just need to write a routine that does the comparison in the order you like.  This would be a better fit for stack overflow than math.  You are looking for an algorithm, not an equation.

Comment: I would like to use a precise equation in a specification. Code is inappropriate.

Comment: I am also asking to learn how to say such things in math.

Comment: All you are doing is defining a different order of the characters.  It would be as if I wanted to make a dictionary where $r$ comes after $j$ and before $k$.  There is nothing mathematical about it except defining the order.  Just list all the characters in the order you like for your specification.

Comment: There’s more to it than having a list. How do I express the index of the letter “A” in a list and compare that index with the index of the letter “B”?

Comment: All you have to do it come up with an order of the characters.  Then you translate each character to its position in the list and do a lexicographic sort on the strings of positions.  Maybe $A$ is in position $15$ in the list and $B$ is in position $27$.  Then $AB$ becomes $15,27$.  If $C$ is in position $23$, $CC$ will become $23,23$ and come after $AB$ and before $BA$

Comment: Right, but my question is, how do I translate each character to its position, in math notation?

Comment: You just make a list of the characters in order.  Then you can make a table of each with its position.  That is a fine way to define a function, which is what you want, from character to position in the list.  An equation would only help if there were some regularity to your order.  If you wanted all the letters in even positions in the usual order to come before the ones in odd positions, you could make an equation to encapsulate that idea.  If your out of usual order things are scattered, a table or list will be easier.

Comment: Can you show me how to define that function properly so it translates a letter to its index in a list?

Comment: Literally, two columns. $\begin {array} {c c} A&1\\B&2\\F&3\\j&4 \end {array}$ and so on.  Then sort on the numbers.  Or just a list $ABFj$ is equivalent to the table I gave.

Comment: How is that a function definition? Where’s the $f(x)$, and what do you do with $x$?

Comment: $x$ is a character in the set.  $f(x)$ is the number next to it in the table.  Each string of text gets translated to a string of numbers, then you sort the strings and translate the numbers back into characters.  Using this table, ABj would become 1,2,4.  If $e$ were $5$ then AeA would come after Ajj

Comment: How do you formally define such a function? $f(x) :  ???$

Comment: That is exactly what I said in my last comment.  When the domain is finite, like a set of characters, a list with the output for each input is a fine way of defining a function.  ASCII is the reverse of this.  You give it a number in the range $0-127$ and it returns a character.  You just want to change the mapping between characters and numbers, so that when the sort algorithm works on the numbers, the characters come out in a different order.  There is nothing wrong with that, but a list of the mapping is a good definition and does not rely on any regularity in the remapping.